# three.js OrbitControls follow mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made some website that implemented with three.js for a 3d graphical project.

I have to use `OrbitControls` for zoom in/out with mouse wheel. (And now I'm using it)

But I wonder that `OrbitControls` has some properties that can make the camera follow mouse pointer?

Reference site is here: `https://50-jahre-hitparade.ch/`

Access that site and move the mouse pointer, camera follows the mouse pointer.

I want to implement 100% same with the above site's camera move.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in that example they are probably just setting camera.rotation.x and .y as the normalized cursor screen coordinate.

Comment: So, I just detect `event.screenX`, `event.screenY` and set `camera.rotation.x = event.screenX`, `camera.rotation.y = event.screenY`?

Comment: not quite. You'll have to divide the event x/y by the width and height of the canvas, to get it into 0 - 1 space.... then subtract 0.5 from each to get it centered.. (now you're in -0.5 to +0.5 space) then multiply by how many degrees (in radians) you want the camera to rotate.. so like (Math.PI*0.5) will give you 45 degrees in each direction...

Comment: Ok. I will check. anyway, did you know that site use `OrbitControls` or `FirstPersonControls`?

Comment: I dont think they are using either of those controls. The behavior looks like what I described. Also probably uses a mousewheel listener.